# Homebrew installer hangs while installing CommandLineTools on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install Homebrew onto an Intel MacBookPro (macOS Catalina), but while running `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
in Terminal, it seems to hang while installing CommandLineTools (the specific line it hangs on is `==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress`).

I already have a full install of Xcode 11 on this machine (which from what I have heard installs Xcode CommandLineTools).

After navigating to /tmp, I found that it did successfully run `touch` and create the file described in the command it ran, but never wrote anything to it.

I waited for about an hour with no avail. Here is the log:

```html
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following existing directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib
==> The following existing directories will have their owner set to (redacted for privacy):
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib
==> The following existing directories will have their group set to admin:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/var
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/var/homebrew
/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Caskroom
/usr/local/Frameworks
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u+rwx /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown (redacted for privacy) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod ug=rwx /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown (redacted for privacy) /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R (redacted for privacy):admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Users/(redacted for privacy)/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Users/(redacted for privacy)/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R (redacted for privacy) /Users/(redacted for privacy)/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. I tried installing Command Line Tools(CLT) but I got the same finding software dialogue box that never progressed after a minute.

For me, it turns out that I didn't have Xcode at all and the CLT seems to be dependant on Xcode. I didn't have the Library/developer directory either.

I downloaded and installed Xcode, I still couldn't use the command line to install CLT tho, I had to download that and install manually as well.

After getting that all setup homebrew no longer tries to install CLT and is able to complete its install successfully.

I'm new to Mac and have never used before. I started at a new company and they supplied it and I'm not sure if it was pre-used as it has some apps already installed. Perhaps Xcode got removed or never existed for me.
This page explains the whole process in detail for Xcode and CLT
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-download-and-install-xcode/

Comment: This is not what most of the users want. They want to simply use Command Line Tools whilst they don't want to be an Apple device developer. It's because of this that command line tools installation tool is available.

Comment: Well, I don't know why CLT didn't install for me then. Perhaps if I just DL and installed CLT manually that would work in which case my assumption that there was a dependancy on Xcode is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I'd reinstall Xcode command line tools:

1. `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
2. `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Will try that tomorrow morning, thanks!

Comment: No problem, good luck and welcome to Stack Overflow! (you can try step 2 alone first, it may work) I haven't had to use macOS in a while but this used to do the trick a couple of years ago.

Comment: Uh oh- It seems to have got stuck on "Finding software." in the dialog box. This time, I left it for about 7 hours to no avail. Thanks in advance if anyone could help with this!

Comment: Hmmm you can try `xcode-select --reset`. How did you install Xcode?

Comment: I just did it straight through the App Store. I don’t have a CommandLineTools directory under /Library/Developer.

Comment: I haven't done macOS development in a while, but in my limited experience, it's almost always better to download (and maintain) your Xcode as a separate download (especially when the time to run two versions at the same time or more comes... and it will). For that I recommend you [download it from Apple and not from the Appstore](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ide/); now perhaps someone with more recent experience can help you with the Appstore version. Good luck!

Comment: I had to remove it as @MartinMarconcini suggested, but couldn't use the install command. I had to go to the Apple site (used the link in his comment) and download it from there. You should take note of your XCode version and search for your version of the CLT. This link will take you directly to the XCode version list https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

This same happen with me. following steps help me to solve it.

1. Install XCode from Apple Store
2. Restart your macbook
3. Now try to install brew by command:  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Comment: After wasting of many hours, the second step (Restart0 did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the command line tools from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode since the automatically prompted download just hangs. From there you can select the corresponding CLT version to your Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

```html
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following existing directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib
==> The following existing directories will have their owner set to (redacted for privacy):
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib
==> The following existing directories will have their group set to admin:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/var
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/var/homebrew
/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Caskroom
/usr/local/Frameworks
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u+rwx /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown (redacted for privacy) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod ug=rwx /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown (redacted for privacy) /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R (redacted for privacy):admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Users/(redacted for privacy)/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Users/(redacted for privacy)/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R (redacted for privacy) /Users/(redacted for privacy)/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have an Older version of Mac OS (Catalina) and I could not download XCode from App store. So I installed it externally from apple official developer archive and I faced the same issue

What I did to solve this issue was that I downloaded the Command Line tools for my XCode version from the same official developer archive and installed it manually. It was like 2.5 or 2.6 GB size Program and the setup was like 500 MB .dmg file.

After that When I installed homebrew It was very quick.

Answer (score -2):

Same happened to me. I had to upgrade to macOS Monterey (I was on Big Sur still).