# brew install stuck for hours

Tags: android, xcode, macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

My brew install stuck at "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress"
I kept laptop on for almost a day but its not moving forward

This script will install:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R ab:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
```

""Stuck here""

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homebrew installer hangs while installing CommandLineTools on macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71140369/homebrew-installer-hangs-while-installing-commandlinetools-on-macos-catalina)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just run into this issue, for me it is basically because Xcode command line tools cannot be installed (brew has a dependency on xcode commandline tools so it will try to install it if it is missing).

The workaround I get is downloading the xcode commandline tool form https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ and install it manually. Then running brew installer should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

To install Xcode Command Line Tools, you can also just enter *xcode-select --install* at a Terminal prompt, and that will trigger a built-in online installation process.